# Creation of SSL .crt & .key files using Nginx Cookbook and placing it in Chef-Client

Tags: nginx, chef-infra, cookbook

create ssl certificate and key on nginx cookbook and help me place it in the below mentioned location:

Attribute in Nginx `attributes/default.rb`

`default['nginx']['ssl_certificate'] = '/etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt' 
 default['nginx']['ssl_certificate_key']='/etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key'`

Configuration in Nginx `templates/default/default.conf.erb`

`    server {
     listen       443;

```
 server_name  <%= node['nginx']['server_name'] %>;

 ssl <%= node['nginx']['ssl'] %>;
 ssl_certificate <%= node['nginx']['ssl_certificate'] %>;
 ssl_certificate_key <%= node['nginx']['ssl_certificate_key'] %>;

 #charset koi8-r;
 access_log  <%= node['nginx']['access_log'] %>;

 #error_page  404              /404.html;

 # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html

 error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
 location = /50x.html {
    root   <%= node['nginx']['root'] %>;
 }

 # Default application configuration

 location / {
    proxy_redirect    off;
    proxy_pass http://backend/lgweb1/;
    proxy_set_header Host               $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy  true;
    proxy_cookie_domain localhost <%= node['nginx']['server_name'] %>;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
 }
 location /media {
    if ($request_method != GET) {
        return 403;
    }
    set $args $args&user.name=ec2-user&op=OPEN;
    proxy_pass <server name>;

    }
} 
# Redirect all port 80 access to ssl.
server {
  listen 80;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}`
```

Now I am looking for a simple code which would install both .crt and .key files in their respective locations.

P.S. Cookbooks available in Chef market have too many configurations which I don't need nor do I understand them as I'm a newbee to CHEF and Coding itself.

Note: Im using AMI system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is the `certificate` cookbook on the supermarket.  It will expect a databag with the certificate and key inside, and will place that certificate and key in the specified location while also setting the correct permissions on it.  The documentation on the cookbook is really good, so even a newbie should be able to make good use of it.

Comment: I manually created the nginx.crt and nginx.key in Files directory and used Cookbook_File in recipes/default.rb to place them in the respective locations. It worked

Comment: Please realize that will expose your private key in plain text within your cookbook (in source control and anywhere else it is copied - like on your node).  Probably fine for development, but not a very safe plan for production.

Comment: Are the databags the safest way for production?

Comment: I would say that encrypted data bags are the most common approach today, but there really isn't a "great" approach, just a lot of "ok" approaches.  Coderanger has a great blog post on it https://coderanger.net/chef-secrets/.  He's really one of the best out there regarding Chef, and even he doesn't seem happy with the existing solutions.

Comment: TejayCardon, I will go through the blog. Its been great learning chef, with help from incredible people like you and @tenisibai